# How to route requests with the same query parameter to the same backend servers?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, http, haproxy, nginx-ingress

I have three Nginx reverse proxy servers with ModSecurity installed acting as WAF servers which route requests to my Kubernetes Cluster `ingress-nginx`, Istio service mesh is installed on the Kubernetes cluster and both the Nginx servers and ingress-nginx are the free versions.

Most of my applications exist on the Kubernetes cluster except for three backend servers with a specific application that cannot be run on the Kubernetes cluster.

There web socket requests like the below:

```http
wss://some.domain.com/socket.io/app/?roomId=2
```

I want to implement session persistence based on the query parameter, meaning I need the requests with the same `roomId` query parameter to be routed to the same backend servers which are outside the Kubernetes Cluster, after searching the internet I have several solutions such as using HAProxy stick tables or upgrading to Nginx Plus so I can use its session persistence capabilities, and even using dynamic routing of Istio, however, I don't know what the best approach is.

I have created an `endpoint` for each backend server such as below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: backend-server-1
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.1.100
    ports:
      - port: 80
```

But I don't know how to create Kubernetes services, Istio VirtualServices, and correct ingress-nginx definition to achieve my goal, it could be a mistake to write an endpoint per each backend server I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

Question: How can I send the requests with the same `roomId` query parameter to the same backend server which are not on the Kubernetes Cluster and in which layer should I configure them ( edge Nginx nodes, Ingress-nginx, Istio, added HAProxy layer, etc )?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.
Please tell me if any more information is needed and I apologize in advance for the lack of info.

Comment: Have you checked http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#hash

Comment: According to my knowledge this module can be used to create a server pool so in ( default configuration ) the requests will be routed to the backend servers in the round robin mode, I don't understand how am I able to use this module to extract the query parameter I need and then establish session persistence based on that parameter for all the requests and route them to a single backend server corresponding to that query parameter, if this is possible with this module please guide me on how to.

Comment: Round robin is default method. But using some directives you could change it. E.g. using `hash` (the link above is to this directive, not to the upstream module as whole). Something like this `upstream app { server back1; server back2; server back3; hash $arg_roomId; }`

Comment: I understand better now, makes much more sense, thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now revert back if you are still facing some issues or please post the resolution steps here as a response so that it will be helpful for remaining community members.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue is not resolved since after research I've found out that what I need is basically the sticky session concept or persistent session which is only available in the expensive Nginx Plus subscription. In addition, apparently, Nginx is not able to extract query param by default and some lua scripts must be added ( I'm not sure about this part since I've stopped digging deeper after hitting paywall.) Currently I'm working to achieve my goal through utilizing HAProxy and am waiting for the result to answer my own question.